# Invocation of scheduled class : starts - schedules - completes without a trace. No debug log

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, asynchronous

I've got an Apex Class that implements `System.Schedulable` which I'm trying to run:

```
public class Broker {

    //...

    public class Worker implements System.Schedulable {
        public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
            //fail hard
            System.assert(false, 'CHOO CHOO');
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

I'm invoking it with the usual trick to run momentarily:

```
//leave a bit of space, eg '36 53 9 9 8 ? 2014'
DateTime now = System.now().addSeconds(5);
String cron = now.second() + ' ' + now.minute() + ' ' + now.hour() + ' ' + now.day() + ' ' + now.month() + ' ' + '?' + ' ' + now.year();

//schedule for execution
Broker.Worker schedule = new Broker.Worker();
System.schedule('Worker for ' + cron, cron, schedule);
```

First, I can see it in my `Scheduled Apex` monitor:

[image: scheduled-apex]

And second, I see it progress after a couple seconds from `Next Scheduled Run` to `Started`:

[image: scheduled-jobs]

But it appears to be disappearing into oblivion! The job goes to `Completed` without a trace, leaves no side effects, and no entry in the Debug Log under any user.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a Salesforce bug.

As a work around, promote your `System.Schedulable` class from an inner  to an outer class.

(If it is in fact officially not supported for an inner class, perhaps someone could post the Salesforce documentation reference.)